# Emacs: how to get the default theme?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been using the default theme with about 10 faces changed via
`custom-set-faces` for a while now.  But from time to time I want to
try out a couple of the custom themes out there.  The problem is that
they set much more than 10 faces and there's no way to get back to my
previous setup once I've loaded a custom theme.

Just to clarify:

1. I start Emacs with my customization of the default theme `(load "faces")`.  All is good.
2. `load-theme` `wombat`. All is good.
3. `(load "faces")` again: everything is a mess, because a lot of the faces still remain
   in the `wombat` state.

Sometimes separate themes aren't compatible with each other,
e.g. second one sets more faces than the first one and when
returning to the first one everything becomes a mess.

So I wonder if there's something like `load-theme` `default` that
would reset every face imaginable to the default `emacs -q` state.

I could then just tweak it with my 10 custom faces and have my own
theme that would not have the problem that I described.

Answer (score 23):

It seems that `disable-theme` does what you want.

**UPDATE**

Here is one way to get the 'default theme template'

1) Disable any additional theme (using `disable-theme`)

2) Invoke the command `customize-create-theme` it will open a customize interface, which lists all the default faces, which you can customize and create your own theme

If the `customize-create-theme` is called with theme name it will list all the faces that are set by the theme.

Comment: A nice work-around, thanks. But is it possible to get a default theme template?

Comment: Hi @abo-abo, have you tried the command `customize-create-theme`? If the command is invoked with default theme loaded (i.e. no theme loaded) it lists all the default faces, which you can customize and create your own theme.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried something similar from `customize-themes`, but this one is better. Still, custom themes set more faces than this.

Answer (score 8):

Others have mentioned ways to try to *work around* the problem.  I'll just point out that there is, so far, an inherent problem with Emacs custom themes, in terms of trying to "**undo**" them and get back to a previous, possibly customized but not custom-themed state.

Particularly if you want to do this non-interactively, e.g., in the code for a command that lets users try themes out but also lets them cancel (e.g. `C-g`) and return to the previous state, before theming.

You can ***disable*** all themes that were ever enabled in the session, but that will *not* return your session to its state before the themes were enabled.  Disabling a theme is, in effect, only *relative to other themes*, not to an uncustomized state or (especially) to other, non-theme customizations.

See also:

- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-02/msg00334.html
- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15687

(Oh, and FWIW, [***color themes***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme), which were presumably the inspiration for Emacs *custom themes*, do not have this problem.  And they work fine with all Emacs versions, including the latest.  They have different limitations from custom themes, however.  It would be good for the custom theme implementation to be fixed/completed, so custom themes can completely replace color themes.)

Comment: I upvoted, actually. Can't accept, since the issue isn't resolved yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have something like this in my emacs config to change themes:

```
(defun zenburn ()
"Activate zenburn theme."
(interactive)
(setq dark-theme t)
;; disable other themes before setting this theme
(disable-theme 'soft-stone)
(disable-theme 'leuven)
(load-theme 'zenburn t))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer here since you don't necessarily know the current theme:

This removes all custom themes.

```el
(dolist (theme custom-enabled-themes)
  (disable-theme theme))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is like a year after the original, but just solved a similar problem by `M-x customize-face` then entering `default`.

`Customize Face: Default` will give you a GUI with options for things like font, foreground and background colors, etc.

Go to the top area marked `Operate on all settings in this buffer:` and click on `Revert` and in the dropdown, `Erase Customizations`.

Finally, reload/evaluate your `.emacs` or `init.el` file.

This worked for me, while trying to manually disable (almost all) themes and float around .el files hadn't.