# Emacs disable-theme after loading a different one (themes conflict)

Tags: emacs

On Emacs 24.3.1 if I `M-X load-theme` and load another theme, it often interferes with my current theme instead of replacing it, giving a very ugly result colour-wise.

An example is here, where the `solarized-light` and `wombat` themes are conflicting:

[image: solarized-light and wombad conflict]

I solve this by doing a `M-X disable-theme` of the old theme, is there a cleaner way to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: how to get the default theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127337/emacs-how-to-get-the-default-theme)

Comment: abo-abo that does seem related (thanks!), but it's not a duplicate. Also that question has no accepted answer. Looking at your answers to the question there is quite enlightening though - It's quite surprising how poor emacs colour supprt is , considering how old the program is and how basic colour support is.

Comment: Short answer, you cannot do this. When a theme is loaded it changes the properties of all supported faces, but it does not reset face properties. What you could do is record the properties of all standard faces before loading any themes, then use those to revert back to the default theme before switching to a new one. However, many packages specify their own faces and it if a custom theme supports that package, those colors wont be reverted. Color themes are a mess.

Comment: @JordonBiondo yikes! I guess customisability sometimes has serious drawbacks.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: I echo what you say, with one exception: What you describe is about ***custom*** themes, not ***color*** themes, so I would correct your last sentence to "***Custom*** themes are a mess." See [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) wiki page about the differences between the two kinds of themes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disabling first the active theme certainly helps.

If you add this to your init.el:

```
(defun disable-all-themes ()
  "disable all active themes."
  (dolist (i custom-enabled-themes)
    (disable-theme i)))

(defadvice load-theme (before disable-themes-first activate)
  (disable-all-themes))
```

the function `load-theme` will first disable the active themes, before loading the new one.

Comment: This advice is a bad idea. Themes are _supposed_ to be applicable on top of each other. Packages may rely on that. It's better to define a new command that does the same thing.